# Table index over a complex primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got following tables in my database

- user
- status
- statusToUser

statusToUser works as a link table between the other two for a many to many relationship

the table definition is the following:

- User_Id
- Status_Id

those columns are the primary key for the table and have a single index which holds both of them, but when running a query optimization for "missing queries" I got in the list the suggestion to add over user_id another index.

the question is do I really need another index over just that column, having already the other index?

thanks

Edit:

these are two different queries, same approach:

```
SELECT  user_seeks * avg_total_user_cost * ( avg_user_impact * 0.01 ) AS [index_advantage] ,
        dbmigs.last_user_seek ,
        dbmid.[statement] AS [Database.Schema.Table] ,
        dbmid.equality_columns ,
        dbmid.inequality_columns ,
        dbmid.included_columns ,
        dbmigs.unique_compiles ,
        dbmigs.user_seeks ,
        dbmigs.avg_total_user_cost ,
        dbmigs.avg_user_impact
FROM    sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats AS dbmigs WITH ( NOLOCK )
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups AS dbmig WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    ON dbmigs.group_handle = dbmig.index_group_handle
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details AS dbmid WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    ON dbmig.index_handle = dbmid.index_handle
WHERE   dbmid.[database_id] = DB_ID()
ORDER BY index_advantage DESC ;
```

number 2

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT TOP 20 
ROUND(s.avg_total_user_cost * 
s.avg_user_impact 
* (s.user_seeks + s.user_scans),0) 
AS [Total Cost]
, d.[statement] AS [Table Name]
, equality_columns
, inequality_columns
, included_columns
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups g 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats s 
ON s.group_handle = g.index_group_handle 
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details d 
ON d.index_handle = g.index_handle
ORDER BY [Total Cost] DESC
```

Comment: Well, what does your query look like that is saying you need to add this index?

Comment: Have you tried adding the index on a test system to see if there is a performance difference?

Comment: If your are unsure what indexes are needed why don't you run the ms sql profiler, log all queries while they are executed and use those transactions.rc files to run the database optimizer tools using the tuning profile. It analyse your statements and suggest what indexes and statistics to be set on your database. Works pretty well at all.

Comment: If you already have an index on `(user_id, status_id)` (in that order), then a separate index on just `(user_id)` won't do you any good. Those recommendations are to be taken with caution - they're **NOT** perfect! Sometimes they suggest an index that you already have - or like here: an index that really doesn't make any sense at all. Take those as *hints* - but don't just blindly do everything these DMV's suggest.....

Comment: @steoleary I did dome testing and comparing both queries in two different databases ran the query measure the time and I have to teel it improved a lot just by adding a non-clustered index to both columns, but to me I see that as a potential index duplication, but that's topic for another question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both fields in a junction table is foreign keys to other tables. It is usually a good idea to have a index on the foreign keys so a clustered key on `(user_id, status_id)` and a non clustered on `(status_id, user_id)` would be a good idea.

A `delete` in the `status` table or in the `user` table will have to check the existence of rows in `statusToUser` and if the only index you have is `(user_id, status_id)` the `delete` in `user` can use the primary key but the delete in `status` has to do a clustered index scan of `statusToUser` to verify that there are no rows in there that matches the row that is to be deleted.

The same goes for a predicates on `status` in queries. The primary key on `(user_id, status_id)` will not be of any help and you can end up with a clustered index scan instead of a potential seek or it might need to do an expensive sort operation.